# Dynamic children for TabView using listview and listTile

Tags: flutter, dart

[Dynamic children for TabView in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117894/dynamic-children-for-tabview-in-flutter/56218359)

It does work well, but after creating the tabbarview based on the categories, I'm creating a listview with listtile for the content, it does work as intended, the only problem is that each listtile created as a ontap which I need, but I can only get a tap from the last one created.. how can I solve this?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _poiCatList = catPoi.currentCatPoiList.where((poi) => poi.IsActive == true && poi.IsFeatured == false).toList(); // filtra cat de pois
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: _poiCatList.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs:
              List<Widget>.generate(_poiCatList.length, (int index){
                  var _selectedIcon = poiIconSet.currentPoiIconSetList.firstWhere((icon) => icon.Id == _poiCatList[index].CGBO_POIICONSET_ID);  // escolhe icon correto
                  return new Tab(icon: Icon(poiIconSet.iconSet[_selectedIcon.Name.toLowerCase()]), text: _poiCatList[index].Name);
              }),
            ),
            title: Text("City Guide - Point's of Interest"),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
              children:
                List<Widget>.generate(_poiCatList.length, (int tabIndex){
                  _poiList = poi.currentPoiList.where((poi) => poi.IsActive == true && poi.IsFeatured == false && poi.CG_CATPOI_ID == _poiCatList[tabIndex].Id).toList(); // filtra pois pela cat
                  return new ListView(
                      children:
                        List<Widget>.generate(_poiList.length, (int tileIndex){
                          return new ListTile(
                              title: new Text(_poiList[tileIndex].Title, style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
                              subtitle: new Text(_poiList[tileIndex].Address),
                              leading: new Icon(
                                Icons.place,
                                color: Colors.blue[500],
                              ),
                              trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _currentSelectPoi = tileIndex;
                                });
                                _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("You clicked item number $_currentSelectPoi ")));

                              },
                          );
                        }
                       )
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? It will be impossible to know what's going on without looking at your code.

Comment: @SpencerStolworthy just updated with some code..

Comment: Thanks Pedro. Could you explain in different words what is going on? As I read through your description, I have a hard time understanding exactly what the symptoms are. Thanks :)

Comment: @SpencerStolworthy it was my own fault actually, this was the problem : _poiList = poi.currentPoiList.where((poi) => poi.IsActive == true && poi.IsFeatured == false && poi.CG_CATPOI_ID == _poiCatList[tabIndex].Id).toList(); ... just fixed it and now the behaviour is correct.