# Display Tab Bar View Products According to Tab Bar Name in Flutter

Tags: flutter, filter, dynamic, tabs, flutter-layout

So, I need to create this kind of an eCommerce application, Here's the UI :

[Here's the design of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Grfq.png)

It has two levels of categories as seen in the design.

I'm using Tab Bar and Tab Bar View, to create the category hierarchy. I'm nesting the second level category in the tab bar view of the first and similarly for the product data.

My Query, here is: How Do I filter the generated tab bar view content according to the name of the tab bar.

[Dynamic children for TabView in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117894/dynamic-children-for-tabview-in-flutter)

I'm referring to this to create dynamic data for the tab but how Do I filter the tab bar view conditionally to the tab bar?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

create a widget function that accepts name and returns lists with given name like this:

```
Widget home(String txt){
return yourWidget();///filtered by txt variable
}
```

and call this method like:

```
TabBarView(
        controller: _nestedTabController,
        children: <Widget>[
         home("Milk"),
         home("Diary"),
          home("Cheese"),
     ])
```

Comment: Thanks! But Both the tab bar and nested tab are having dynamic content. So, then the nested tab bar would also be a list of objects and same goes with the tab bar?  So, then how do I render them accordingly. So, like Tab Bar -> Nested Tab Bar -> Filtered Products. How Do I tell the Dynamic Nested Tab about the Parent Tab Bar and to render according to the parent tab bar. Any kind of help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: so use it like object[0] object[1] instead of milk and diary

Comment: Yeah, but those objects will be created on the fly, by fetching items from the server? So, then In that scenario, how can I establish a child and parent relationship between the Tab Bar -> Nested Tab Bar ? Like how can i create a connection between tab bar and tab bar view indexes?

Comment: you can use FutureBuilder(future:fetchData(),builder(context,snapshot){return TabBarView(childred:[//childs])} you can do it like this after you fetch data  from server